# Check whether string contains sub string, without using the java predefined methods

Tags: java, string, substring

I need to find whether a given sub string contains within a given string.But the constraint is I cannot use any predefined Java methods.
I have tried as follows.

```
public void checkAvailability()
{
    len=st.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<substr.length();j++)
        {
            if(st.charAt(i)==substr.charAt(j))
            {
                if(j!=substr.length()-1 && i!=st.length()-1)
                {
                    if(st.charAt(i+1)==substr.charAt(j+1))
                    {
                        available=true;
                        //j++;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(available)
    {
        System.out.println("The character is available " + count + " times");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The character is not availabe");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't give the correct answer. Can somebody help please?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: In what way is the answer incorrect? Can you give us a few examples?

Comment: Enter the string: QWERTYQWERTYQWFDS

Enter the sub string: QWE

The character is available 3.0 times

This is the out put for the above given inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code - I'll describe an algorithm without writing the code to avoid spoiling the learning exercise for you:

- The outer loop needs to go from 0 to `st.length()-substr.length()`
- The inner loop needs to check `st.charAt(i+j)` and `substr.charAt(j)`
- The inner loop needs to stop as soon as you find a mismatch; set a mismatch flag, and break
- If the inner loop completes without finding a mismatch, then `i` is the position of the first match.

Note that this is the most straightforward algorithm. It does not perform well when the `st` is long, and `substr` has lots of "false positives" In general, you can do better than that, for example, by using the [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: public void checkAvailability()
    {
     len=st.length();
     for(int i=0;i<st.length()-substr.length();i++)
     {
      for(int j=0;j<substr.length();j++)
      {
       if( st.charAt(i+j)==substr.charAt(j))
       {
        if(j!=substr.length()-1 && i!=st.length()-1)
        {
         if(st.charAt(i+1)==substr.charAt(j+1))
         {
          available=true;
          //j++;
          count++;
         }
        }
        else
        {
         mismatch=true;
         break;
        }
       }
      }
     }

Comment: Is that the way you told? But I didn't get a solution.

Comment: @Dini88 That's better, but not quite right: the first `if` should check inequality `!=`, and there should be no second `if`. Take a look: [link](http://ideone.com/T9iSFm).

Comment: That works fine..Thanks.
Can you tell me a way to get the number of times that the substring contains in the string?

Comment: @Dini88 There are two ways to produce an answer to this question. Consider an example: how many times `xx` is contained in `xxxxxx`? Both answers 3 and 5 are correct: answer 3 counts non-overlapping substrings, i.e. when each character could be part of no more than one match; answer 5 allows overlaps. For the answer with overlaps, increment a counter instead of `println`, and remove the second `break`; for the answer with no overlaps you would need to adjust `i` by length of `substr`, and remove the second `break` as well.